# Java: Get root directory,drive letter, or computer name of folder (System Independent)

Tags: java, file

Is there a cleaner way in getting the root directory name, drive letter, or computer name of a given directory other than string manipulation?

For example:

C:\myfolder\file.txt will return C:\

//NETWORK_COMPUTER/myfolder/file.txt will return //NETWORK_COMPUTER/

/temp/myfolder/file.txt will return /temp/

Note: I have already checked [Get partition name from drive letter and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064923/get-partition-name-from-drive-letter-and-vice-versa) and [Fetching file and path from network using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991294/fetching-file-and-path-from-network-using-java).

Also, this problem is restricted to JDK 6

Comment: Use [Files.getFileStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getFileStore-java.nio.file.Path-) to get the FileStore of the directory, then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678363/find-the-directory-for-a-filestore .

Comment: I forgot to note that this problem is a jdk 6 restricted.